# Why I can't upload image and video in html?

Tags: php, html

I Have this kind of code.. how can I make the php for upload with this code?
Anyone can help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my php for that. But it seems wrong because it is error

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))
```

This part for check the video size

```
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = $temp[0].'_'.round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);

      // move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"].'_'.time());
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $newfilename;
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Why my image can't be uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From W3Schools.

- Create your php file `upload_file.php` and copy paste the following code.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

You are going to want to follow the tutorial here
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp